# Does Conduit Fill Rule have to be followed?

Tags: conduit

I previously concluded that I can use 1/2" sch-40 with a .622 ID to house three 8awg HTTN stranded wires. The area inside conduit is .3038 sq in. Each wire is .0353 so three wires is .1059. Since .1059/.3038 = 34.86% fill ratio. After purchasing several lengths of this conduit from big orange, I learn they sell Cantex brand and the ID is actually .578. This   ID .2623 sq in so my situation is .1059/.2623 = 40.37% fill. I wanted to use an insulated ground but can use a bare wire, assume solid. Is the rule hard and fast or can I squeak by at 40% ??
Appreciate candid replies.
Thanks, Ron

Comment: Where did you get this information from? The HD page for Cantex 1/2" 40 https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-2-in-x-10-ft-Sch-40-PVC-Conduit-A52AE12H/202352535 says 0.622 ID.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the nominal dimensions found in Chapter 9 of the NEC for your fill calculations? I can bet you dollars to donuts that that's what the inspector will be basing their fill calcs on when they check your work

Comment: Guess keyword is "nominal" (both answers), the least of which is .602 (NEC). Oddly .622 is the NEC nominal for EMT conduit in 1/2". The Cantex website has a drawing and has .578 shown as a MIN. I'll use the .602 with three 8awg HTTN all with insulation which yields .1059/.2846=37.21% on paper. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe anyone other than an inspector with a calculator and a vendetta against you will say you failed because you are over capacity by 0.37%.

Answer (score 1):

If your circuit is 15A to 30A, in those circuit sizes the ground must be the same size as the conductors.  For 35-60A circuits, ground can be #10.

There is a rule that says when you enlarge conductors larger than they need to be, you must enlarge the ground in proportion.  Thus if your circuit is 15-30A (same size ground) and you're enlarging the wire to #8, you must enlarge the ground as well.

However, for 35-50A circuits, #8 copper is the smallest legal size. Thus you are NOT enlarging the primary conductors and do not need to enlarge the standard #10 ground.

The ground may be bare if copper.

Now a funny exception happens with EV Energy Management Systems aka EVSEs aka [Quote Chargers Unquote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y).  Their job is to tell the car the amps it can safely take from the house's service.  The installer does a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation on the service (and subpanel if applicable), and then sets that during commissioning. Well if you find out you can only safely use a 20A breaker, but your EVSE is capable of more than 30A, then you can leave it on a 35-50A breaker and not have to upsize the ground.  Just commission the EVSE for a 20A breaker.